# How to save object property with ODATA?

Tags: c#, odata

I have these classes, when I save Invoice

```
string serviceUri = "http://myserviceurl.azurewebsites.net/odata/";
var container = new Default.Container(new Uri(serviceUri));

var myInvoice = container.Invoice.Expand("CreatedBy").Where(x => x.Id == new Guid("B7E5EEAD-EA77-4174-8305-50440AD057C7")).Skip(0).First();
myInvoice.CreatedBy = container.User.First();
container.UpdateObject(myInvoice);
```

It saves the Invoice (fields: GUID, string), but the **CreatedBy** User field does not get saved (it is not sent to the server, on server side I checked it and comes **null**)

How can I fix it, or is it a limitation in ODATA 4?

Should I use ODATA only to *Read*; 
and create another WebApi to *Save* the Entire Invoice Entity (including CreatedBy) ? Comments, solutions will be appreciated.

```
[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class User
{
    [Index]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Invoice
{
    [Index]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }    // how to save this?

    [InverseProperty("Invoice")]
    public ICollection<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; }    // how to save this?
 }

[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class InvoiceItem
{
    [Index]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

On these scenarios, is ODATA suitable only to READ? to WRITE, I should write my own WebApi?
Some thing like this: (or maybe a generic version of this)

```
public void Post([FromBody] Invoice p)
{
    SyncContext db = new SyncContext();

    db.Entry(p).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; // Exists?

    foreach (var item in p.Items)
    {
        var f = db.InvoiceItem.Where(i => i.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        db.Entry(item).State = f == null ?
                            System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added :
                            System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Client side:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myInvoice);
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    client.UploadString(new Uri("http://localhost:56948/odata/Invoice"), "POST", dataString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the user as a foreign key to the invoice. Because your user ID is created by the database you will need to create the user first.

[Example] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4)

```
public class Invoice
{
    ...
    // New code:    
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid userId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good. The User was created before, I set It, but ODATA still does not send this field. myInvoice.CreatedBy = container.User.First(); // Get the User from the container

Comment: Remove CreatedBy from Invoice and add userId.  public Guid userId. The example will walk you through what you need to do.

Comment: If you are saying you can not GET the user, what does your URI look like?

Comment: I can Get the User, and set it to the CreatedBy field. But when saved, it does not get sent to server side. The entity only send planar fields, not the other object types.

Answer (score 0):

After some days investigating this issue, and trying it with some libraries, on ODATA 3, ODATA 4, and even MongoDB and DocumentDB,
I can say that this issue is caused by the problem of how deep should the system go and store the data. Depending on the object that is saved, potentially almost entire Database can be reached from a apparently simple save on Invoice.

What I think that can be done is to Implement a Annotation like **[NotRecursive]**, in *CreatedBy*,

So it would only send the Key for that property, not the entire *CreatedBy (User)* graph.

Another possible data annotation would be **[RecursiveLevel(NumberOfLevels)]**

This recursive problem affects all them: Entity, NHibernate, ODATA, and even Document stores like MongoDB and DocumentDB.

There is a need to create a simple specification (Data Annotation) to solve this nested levels definition for saving, on all kinds of Database and ORM/Mappers.